# Save a string on a server using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use AJAX, but it seems it's not working.

```
var data = 'foo bar';
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {data: data},
  success: function(result) {
    alert('success');
  }
});
```

index.php

```
<?php
$x = $_POST["data"];
file_put_contents ('data.txt', data);
```

I get a success alert, but `data.txt` is empty. I have no idea why is this not working.

I am using XAMPP to test on local server.

Comment: You need to use AJAX and help from server side script like php.

Comment: Can you provide more data about your current setup? As it is we have no idea if you are running a PHP server, Node.js, or any kind of server at all.

Comment: I am running on a local server using xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using only javascript you can not write files on a **server**, because your javascript runs on the client side (the browser).
You need either `Ajax` and a server side script (like `PHP`) to handle the saving, or if you only want to use it with one browser (chat with yourself?), you can store stuff with javascript in the localstorage of the browser, but be aware that this storage does not last forever.

Comment: And why exactly is someone downvoting my answer?